# How to split up RealmResults into individual parts

Tags: java, android, realm

I have a realm database and I managed to display it on a `recyclerView`.  The issue is, however that it is displaying all the data from one entry together, and I need to split it up.  Here is what it currently displays:

`RealmAcronym = [{acronym:MVP},{acronymFull:exampleText},{color:red}]`

I want to break it up into a String[] where

```
string[0] = acronym;
string[1] = acronymFull;
string[2] = color;
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: I am not quite sure why do you need that, but if you really want to build a string array, you can add a static function to do that like: ```public static String[] getStringArray(RealmAcronym acronym) { return new String [] {acronym.getAcronym(), acronmy.getColor()};```